Integrate AWS MSK to Prometheus running on EC2 in different AWS account
How do i authenticate prometheus server to AWS MKS Services so that prometheus can pull metrics form MSK?
I have enabled monitoring for the kafka cluster as well as JMX/Node Exporter. Also added broker DNS in the prometheus.yml file as targets. Upon re-starting the Prometheus service, data should reflect in the configuration of Prometheus but it is not.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. about configuring monitoring) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
